# How to fix the error in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3.1

I am new on Magento community and a beginner in coding. I need some help because when I try to go to my website admin or my website, there is an message error :Error log record number.

The message error is like this
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 409859914196

It happens just after I tried to clear the store cache

Can anyone help me on this one please

Comment: can you please open and check in var/report/409859914196, what is error there.

Comment: shall i past the error log

Comment: Permission denied in \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/colinmollenhour\/cache-backendfile\/File.php on line 691","1":"<pre>#1 file_put_contents('\/var\/ www\/html\/va...', '952_THEME_BY_ID_...', 10) called at [vendor\/ colinmollenhour\/cache-backend-file\/File.php:691]

Comment: try to do with the permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please do with below command in your ssh:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/
```

**hope its work for you**